# How to model this seat with curved edges/corners

Tags: modeling

I would like model this seat. I'm using version 2.91 at the moment.

[image: IMG002]

I have not found a way to smoothen the blunt edges. Currently this is the state of the seat:

[image: IMG003]

Note that the edges are rounded in the initial image. How would one do this using the least complex method? I am fairly new to Blender, and am not yet familiar with 98% of the functions. I would also like to be able to make the corners rounded. Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest and most common way to achieve "roundness" of a mesh is to use a Subdivision Surface Modifier. However, this often requires what is known as "supporting geometry" which includes things such as placing extra edge loops to help better define (control the "rounding" amount) of edges.  A good place to learn all about it is from this segment of the "Blender Guru's" anvil tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lITV4F_P4E0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, itś really simple, all you have to do is shade it smooth, in other words, find ¨shade smooth¨ and click that. DO NOT just add more faces until it looks smooth, blender will likely crash as it did with me.

Comment: That didn't work at my end. I am beginning to believe that this is an expert level shape. It is the most complex one I've done so far (the edges). It has been stalling this project for near eternity.